# How do you use django-datatable-view

Tags: python, django, datatable

I am currently building a project that will be displaying quite a bit of data in the Django admin I would like to substitute the list view used for datatables using [django-datatable-view](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view) it says in the list for features that it can be dropped in as a replacement for list view. I might be not reading this correctly but from that I think it means totally replace list view so data tables are used by default which is what I want. I am new to Django and there seems to be no documentation on this add-on they have a few samples but no docs on how to actually use features they claim exist has anyone replaced the list view in Django with datatables using this add-on. I want to try and do it by default for all new models created but also the models like auth that I haven't extended yet.

Comment: I think listview in django-datatable-view means https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: Yeah I am trying to replace it with datatables by default

Comment: ruddra's answer helped me get on track with django-datatable-view project, but my answer to another question on this subject may give some other detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713780/2863603

Comment: check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740133/data-table-not-populating-data-in-django-datatable-view/55047474#55047474

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I have tested this app on my localhost, here is some results(too much for comment, so I will answer here)

First, you need to take a look here: http://django-datatable-view.appspot.com/

It has got some documentation about how to implement django-datatable-view. For example:
http://django-datatable-view.appspot.com/zero-configuration/ has got how to write a view to implement a table based on a model,

http://django-datatable-view.appspot.com/ordering/ has got how to get orders in table,

http://django-datatable-view.appspot.com/javascript-initialization/ has got information about `js`.

Better if you clone the repo and run it in localhost. There you will be able to experiment with the views and templates(as I tried to do/did).

In here: https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view/blob/master/datatableview/tests/example_project/example_project/example_app/views.py, you will see how multiple types of view(For no configuration table, specific column table etc) has been coded.

Second, what have I tried so far:
My structure for this project was like this:

```
-Project
 manage.py
   -myapp(folder)
      views.py
      models.py
      urls.py
   -datatableview*(folder)
   -projectapp(folder)
      settings.py
      urls.py
```

*From cloned repo, I copied datatableview folder and pasted it in my project.

In myapp>models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
       title= models.CharField(max_length=150)
       body = models.TextField()
       created = models.DateField()
```

In myapp>views:

```
class MyView(DatatableView):
    model = Post
    datatable_options = {
        'columns': [
            'title',
            'body',
            'created',
            ]
    }
```

In myapp>urls:

```
url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(),  name='myview'),
```

In templates:
   in (tempaltes/myapp/post_list.html)

```
{% block content %}
{{ datatable }}
{{ object_list }} 
{% endblock %}
```

Result was like this:

```
title   body    created
[<post: one >, <post: two>]
```

here `title body created` are names of table's column header.

PS: I know its not much of a help, but hopefully this information will help you go further. And a little recommendation, please take a look at [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: is there a way to integrate [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) with [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: while this answer helps, the result is certainly not desirable. How can you actually render the table instead of just the list of objects?