# How to render tables in django-datatable-view?

Tags: python, django, datatable, html-table

I can't figure out how to render an editable table using `Django-datatable-view`. I want to create a table exactly like this: http://django-datatable-view.appspot.com/x-editable-columns/ from model `City` for example.

I've read the docs and tutorials but still can't figure out how to create the table.

This is what I've done so far:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
    {% load static %}e
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "datatable/js/datatableview.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script>
        datatableview.auto_initialize = false;
        $(function () {
            var xeditable_options = {};
            datatableview.initialize($('.datatable'), {
                fnRowCallback: datatableview.make_xeditable(xeditable_options),
            });
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {{ datatable }}
    {{ object_list }}
{% endblock %}
```

And my view is:

```
class ZeroConfigurationDatatableView(dtv_views.XEditableDatatableView):
    model = dolava_models.City

    datatable_options = {
        'columns': [
            'id',
            ("Name", 'name', dtv_helpers.make_xeditable),
            ("Country", 'country', dtv_helpers.make_xeditable),

        ]
    }
```

Unfortunately my code renders this:

[image]

Comment: you have not defined tables tags.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool If you know how to define tags, you could post an answer. I dont know what do you mean by tags.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool could you explain what you mean by tables tags? Do you mean html table tags?

Answer (score 3):

As the first step, try to run the example project that is buried in:

```
django-datatable-view/datatableview/tests/example_project/example_project/example_app
```

To do this, follow the [Documentation and Live Demos](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view#documentation-and-live-demos) on the projects github page, but be sure to replace `django>=1.4` with `django==1.8` before you start. That is, it is not compatible with django1.9 or 1.10 in my experience.

Once you accomplish this, you will have a full set of working examples and the matching documentation which will ease things a bit. The link that you gave is out of date. Explore the examples (`example_app/views.py`), and the documentation.

When you are ready to get out of the sandbox, follow this route:

1. Start a new virtualenv
2. Clone this branch: `https://github.com/jangeador/django-datatable-view/` (it has a few more commits that make it compatible with recent versions of django), and pip install (use the -e editable option if you plan to make changes).
3. Follow of this example [Datatable object and Meta](http://localhost/configure-datatable-object/) from the example app that you run. In code:

   ```
   class MyDatatable(Datatable):
       class Meta:
           model = Entry
           columns = ['id', 'headline', 'pub_date', 'n_comments', 'n_pingbacks']
           ordering = ['-id']
           page_length = 5
           search_fields = ['blog__name']
           unsortable_columns = ['n_comments']
           hidden_columns = ['n_pingbacks']
           structure_template = 'datatableview/default_structure.html'

   class ConfigureDatatableObjectDatatableView(DatatableView):
       model = Entry
       datatable_class = MyDatatable
   ```

You can delete all attributes in the `Datatable` class if you don't need (they are optional).

Apart from the documentation I had to override the following method on the `DataTableView` class to make it work.

```
def get_template_names(self):
    return "example_base.html"
```

This is your template file, which needs to contain:

```
<script src="{% static 'path-to/datatables.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="{% static 'your-path-to/datatables.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/datatableview.js' %}"></script>

{{ datatable }}

<script>
    // Page javascript
    datatableview.auto_initialize = true;
</script>
```

What is noteworthy here is the inclusion of `datatableview.js` from the django-datatable-view module (and the accompanying `datatableview.auto_initialize = true;`). If you are comfortable with the datatables.js to begin with, you can go ahead and configure it by yourself, but given you are also new to django-datatable-view also, this is probably the easiest route.

Comment: I've tried this, and I still just get a list of the queryset objects. Does this render a table for you?

Comment: @Jed: Yes, it does. For me it works in two steps: 1) regular page load which renders an empty table, 2) an ajax request made by 1 that populates the table. If you are getting just objects check if request is Ajax.

Comment: Thanks, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740133/data-table-not-populating-data-in-django-datatable-view/55047474#55047474

Answer (score 1):

if think you will need this function to render custom column as per your need

```
    def render_column(self, row, column):
            # We want to render user as a custom column
            if column == 'user':
              # escape HTML for security reasons
              return escape('{0} {1}'.format(row.customer_firstname, 
              row.customer_lastname))
           else:
             return super(OrderListJson, self).render_column(row, column)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block content %}
    {% if instances %}
        <table class='datatable'>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            {% for row in instances %}
                <tr>
                  <th> {{ row.id }}</th>
                  <th> {{ row.name }}</th>
                  <th> {{ row.country }}</th>
                </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    {% else %}
        <p>No data available</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: asking rather rendering table in `django-datatable-view`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.